# $match Query in mongodb for different values

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Please help me out how to match the different values in `mongodb`

Example document

```
"payout_info" : [
        {
            "payout_date" : "2019-01-17T18:30:00.000Z", 
            "payment_status" : "Clearing", 
            "bank_trn_number" : "asdfghjklpoiuytrewq", 
            "bank_trn_date" : "2019-01-17T18:30:00.000Z"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Hello and Welcome! Please edit and clarify your question. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a little more info of what do you need help, I will let you some code right here that might help you with you to solve you problem:

```
db.fruit.aggregate([
 {
   $project: {
      "store location" : "$location",
      "has bananas" : {
         $in: [ "bananas", "$in_stock" ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

I took it from [mongodb documentation.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/)